# Looping program back to ''menu''

Tags: java, loops

I just writed this program, it is to train myself for the upcomming exam this monday.

A thing i would like to add is: after a user is done with one of the exchange options `1`/`2`/`3` i would like to give the option to let the user return to the beginning `welcome to the money exchange! etc....`.

i have tried some a for loop and a while loop but i couldn't get it to work.
Would be cool if after the money exchange process that the user get the option to return to the beginning by typing `y` or `n` is this possible?

`/* This program is written as a excercise to prep myself for exams.`
 `* In this program the user can:`
 `* 1. Select a currency (other than euro's)`
 `* 2. Input the amount of money`
`* 3. transfer the amount of currency to euro's`
 `*/`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




    System.out.println(" Welcome to the money exchange! \n Please pick one of the currencies by useing 1 / 2 / 3 \n \n 1 = US dollar \n 2 = GB pounds \n 3 = Yen \n  ");
    System.out.print("Input : ");

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat() ;
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    int choice = input.nextInt() ;
    double transfee = 2.41 ;
    double USrate = 0.9083 ;
    double GBrate = 1.4015 ;
    double YENrate = 0.0075 ;

    if (choice > 3 || choice < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!...... Please try agian\n");
    } else {
        if(choice == 1)  {
            System.out.println("You have choosen for US dollar \n");
            System.out.print("Please enter amount US dollar: ");
            double USamount = input.nextDouble() ;
            double deuros = USamount * USrate ;
            double ddisburse = deuros - transfee ;

            System.out.print("\nInput amount US dollar:. " + USamount + "\n");
            System.out.print("Worth in euro's:........ " + df.format(deuros) + "\n");    
            System.out.print("Transfer cost:.......... " + transfee + "\n");
            System.out.print("Amount to disburse:..... " + df.format(ddisburse) + "\n" );


        }else {
            if(choice == 2){
                System.out.println("You have choosen for GB pounds");
                System.out.print("Please enter amount GB ponds: ");
                double GBamount = input.nextDouble();
                double geuros = GBamount * GBrate ;
                double gdisburse = geuros - transfee;

                System.out.print("\nInput amount GB pound:. " + GBamount + "\n");
                System.out.print("Worth in euro's........ " + df.format(geuros) + "\n");
                System.out.print("Transfer cost:......... " + transfee + "\n");
                System.out.print("Amount to disburse:.... " + df.format(gdisburse) + "\n");


            }else {
                if(choice == 3){
                    System.out.println("You have choosen for Yen");
                    System.out.print("Please enter amount Yen: ");
                    double  YENamount = input.nextDouble();
                    double yeuros = YENamount * YENrate ;
                    double ydisburse = yeuros - transfee ;

                    System.out.print("\nInput amount Yen:... " + YENamount + "\n");
                    System.out.print("Worth in euro's..... " + df.format(yeuros) + "\n");
                    System.out.print("Transfer cost:...... " + transfee + "\n");
                    System.out.print("Amount to disburse:. " + df.format(ydisburse) + "\n");



            }
            }
        }
    }






    }


}
```

Comment: `...} else { if (choice == 2) {` seems a bit odd. Why not just `...} else if (choice == 2) {`? Or use a `switch`-statement.

Comment: basically i would like to  give the user the option to go back to the start,, so the option to choose a currency comes back and the user can run the program agian

Comment: does `...} else if (choice == 2) {` do the same as `...} else { if (choice == 2) {`  ?  thanks for the tip! still learning the basics of java :)

Comment: You could also simplify this a bit by using `else if`, which would allow you to unnest those conditions.  You could also use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your program with a while loop, which checks if the user entered 'y' at the end like this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

class YourClassName
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean askAgain = true;

        while (askAgain)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println(
                    " Welcome to the money exchange! \n Please pick one of the currencies by useing 1 / 2 / 3 \n \n 1 = US dollar \n 2 = GB pounds \n 3 = Yen \n  ");
            System.out.print("Input : ");

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

            int choice = input.nextInt();
            double transfee = 2.41;
            double USrate = 0.9083;
            double GBrate = 1.4015;
            double YENrate = 0.0075;

            if (choice > 3 || choice < 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!...... Please try agian\n");
            } else
            {
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("You have choosen for US dollar \n");
                    System.out.print("Please enter amount US dollar: ");
                    double USamount = input.nextDouble();
                    double deuros = USamount * USrate;
                    double ddisburse = deuros - transfee;

                    System.out.print(
                            "\nInput amount US dollar:. " + USamount + "\n");
                    System.out.print("Worth in euro's:........ "
                            + df.format(deuros) + "\n");
                    System.out.print(
                            "Transfer cost:.......... " + transfee + "\n");
                    System.out.print("Amount to disburse:..... "
                            + df.format(ddisburse) + "\n");

                } else
                {
                    if (choice == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You have choosen for GB pounds");
                        System.out.print("Please enter amount GB ponds: ");
                        double GBamount = input.nextDouble();
                        double geuros = GBamount * GBrate;
                        double gdisburse = geuros - transfee;

                        System.out.print(
                                "\nInput amount GB pound:. " + GBamount + "\n");
                        System.out.print("Worth in euro's........ "
                                + df.format(geuros) + "\n");
                        System.out.print(
                                "Transfer cost:......... " + transfee + "\n");
                        System.out.print("Amount to disburse:.... "
                                + df.format(gdisburse) + "\n");

                    } else
                    {
                        if (choice == 3)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You have choosen for Yen");
                            System.out.print("Please enter amount Yen: ");
                            double YENamount = input.nextDouble();
                            double yeuros = YENamount * YENrate;
                            double ydisburse = yeuros - transfee;

                            System.out.print("\nInput amount Yen:... "
                                    + YENamount + "\n");
                            System.out.print("Worth in euro's..... "
                                    + df.format(yeuros) + "\n");
                            System.out.print(
                                    "Transfer cost:...... " + transfee + "\n");
                            System.out.print("Amount to disburse:. "
                                    + df.format(ydisburse) + "\n");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? (y/n)");
            String againAnswer = input.next();
            askAgain = againAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the boolean variable to `true` first lets you enter the loop. The user will be asked as long as he types an `y` at the end. Every other character would exit the loop:

```
String againAnswer = input.next();
askAgain = againAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
```

You could also check for explicit `n`, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response!,, i also looked at the while statement but i couldt figure out how to apply the loop.. this is a great example !  i have one question though, what does the boolean do for the loop?

Comment: As long as the boolean evaluates to `true`, the loop will run (again). That's why a loop with `while(true)` runs forever (or until you end it with `return` or `break`). At the end of the while loop the boolean value is reassigned, so it will only be true, if the input is `y`or `Y`.

Comment: Thank you very much! i am going to apply this to the program :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the code inside a while loop (`while(true)`). At the end of each `if` block 
add one nested if.

```
System.out.print(Do you want to continue?");
if(in.next().equals("Y")) {
continue;
}
```

And you have add one extra menu(4th) for exit :

```
if(choice == 4){
break;
}
```

Comment: So basicaly i need to add the first code block from your comment in each `if() { } ` statement ?  And the second block at the end of the code to give the user the option to stop the program from looping?

Comment: Thats Correct. One correction.Since you already declared one `Scanner` object variable , you can use that. I have removed that declaration